# Display sunrise and sunset time from agenda view

Tags: org-mode, calendar, diary

I set the diary file as

```
(setq org-agenda-include-diary t)
(setq org-agenda-diary-file "~/Documents/OrgMode/ORG/src/standard-diary") ;;2020-03-02 10:47:06
(setq diary-file "~/Documents/OrgMode/ORG/src/standard-diary")
```

and the Day info in the diary

```
;;Day info
%%(diary-sunrise-sunset)
%%(diary-lunar-phases)
%%(diary-iso-date)
```

Then  check the day view from agenda

```
Tuesday     3 March 2020
               3:00...... -----------------------------------------------------
  Diary:       3:59...... First Quarter Moon (CST)
               6:00...... -----------------------------------------------------
  Diary:       6:46...... Sunrise (CST), sunset 6:07pm (CST) at 40.0N, 116.3E (11:21 hrs daylight)
               9:00...... -----------------------------------------------------
               9:02...... now - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
              12:00...... -----------------------------------------------------
              15:00...... -----------------------------------------------------
              18:00...... -----------------------------------------------------
              21:00...... -----------------------------------------------------
              24:00...... -----------------------------------------------------
```

In the day view the Sunrise time and the sunset time displayed on the same line,
How could place them appropriate the right clock time as

```
Tuesday     3 March 2020
               3:00...... -----------------------------------------------------
  Diary:       3:59...... First Quarter Moon (CST)
               6:00...... -----------------------------------------------------
  Diary:       6:46...... Sunrise (CST) - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
               9:00...... -----------------------------------------------------
               9:02...... now - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
              12:00...... -----------------------------------------------------
              15:00...... -----------------------------------------------------
              18:00...... -----------------------------------------------------
              18:07...... Sunset 6:07pm (CST) at 40.0N, 116.3E (11:21 hrs daylight)
              21:00...... -----------------------------------------------------
              24:00...... -----------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`diary-sunrise-sunset` returns a string with both times:

> "Sunrise 6:17am (EST), sunset 5:36pm (EST) at 40.3N, 71.0W (11:19 hrs daylight)"

So use `diary-sunrise` and `diary-sunset` separately:

```
%%(diary-sunrise)
%%(diary-sunset)
```

where these two functions are defined as follows (somewhere in your init file):

```
(defun diary-sunrise ()
  (let ((dss (diary-sunrise-sunset)))
    (with-temp-buffer
      (insert dss)
      (goto-char (point-min))
      (while (re-search-forward " ([^)]*)" nil t)
        (replace-match "" nil nil))
      (goto-char (point-min))
      (search-forward ",")
      (buffer-substring (point-min) (match-beginning 0)))))

(defun diary-sunset ()
  (let ((dss (diary-sunrise-sunset))
        start end)
    (with-temp-buffer
      (insert dss)
      (goto-char (point-min))
      (while (re-search-forward " ([^)]*)" nil t)
        (replace-match "" nil nil))
      (goto-char (point-min))
      (search-forward ", ")
      (setq start (match-end 0))
      (search-forward " at")
      (setq end (match-beginning 0))
      (goto-char start)
      (capitalize-word 1)
      (buffer-substring start end))))
```

Each of these calls `diary-sunrise-sunset` and parses the return value to get one of the two times.

In order for the times to be correct you have to supply your location, e.g.:

```
(setq calendar-latitude 40.3)
(setq calendar-longitude -71)
```

That's somewhere in the Atlantic off of New York City: adjust to taste.

Note that `diary-sunset` does capitalize `sunset` but it also strips the location off, which is fine for me: you'll have to change the parsing a bit in the second function if you want to keep it.

EDIT in response to comment: It's actually not a very good code example to learn elisp from. It's only doing regexp matching and string operations for one. But the biggest problem is that the diary functions in general (and `diary-sunrise-sunset` in particular) require that a variable named `date` be set before you can call them. So to really run them e.g. in the `*scratch*` buffer in lisp-interaction-mode, you have to say something like this:

```
(setq date '(3 14 2020))
(diary-sunrise-sunset)
```

The date is a list of three numbers: the month, the day and the year.

Comment: amazing and excellent code example to learn elisp for the next days , thank you.

Comment: Thanks so much! I tried this but I get only the label: "Sunset" instead of "Sunset 6:07pm (CST) at 40.0N, 116.3E (11:21 hrs daylight)". Not sure what I am doing wrong. I followed the guidelines to the mm :) (and same for sunrise, of course. I would be nice to get the longer string with the data on location and day length).

Comment: Alternative implementation suggestion:

`(defun diary-sunrise ()
  (let ((dss (diary-sunrise-sunset)))
    (save-match-data
      (string-match "^Sunrise \\([^ ]*\\) " dss)
      (concat " " (match-string 1 dss))
      )))

(defun diary-sunset ()
  (let ((dss (diary-sunrise-sunset)))
    (save-match-data
      (string-match ", sunset \\([^ ]*\\) " dss)
      (concat " " (match-string 1 dss))
      )))`

Comment: Please make your comment into an answer: comments are not meant to contain large amounts of code and they are meant to ask/provide clarifications/corrections, not alternative implementations. As an answer, your code will also be much more visible (and you may earn some reputation points too - which is not the case with comments).

Comment: @EmmanuelGoldstein: sorry I missed your question. You have to set `calendar-latitude` and `calendar-longitude` for your location as described in the question. Otherwise, you don't get any information out of the function. See the debugging info in the EDIT as well.